# Command for downloading all website project files

Tags: server, digital-ocean, putty

I have access to server of our company's website. I access it using Putty.
I want to download all files(index.php, any jpg files for favicons, etc.) used for deployment of the web project. When I told to programmer of website to share the full script(HTML,CSS,PHP, jquery plugins), he said that I can access the entire code from server.
When I enter the server via Putty(private key+ssh), and then I type "ls" I see that there are "index.php" and "mysql" files, the full contents of which I cannot download.
What are the useful resources for list of commands?
Which command should I use to download the project folder containing all files with code and without code?
P.S. I do not know if this information is  necessary, but the website was deployed using DigitalOcean.

Comment: You can collect all the files into one archive with the `tar` command, and then compress that with `gzip` or `bzip2` or `xz`, and then download it with `sftp` or `scp` or `filezilla`.

Comment: Filezilla allows for an sftp protocol, which is like ssh'ing into the server in the sense that it won't matter if traditional FTP is enabled. That will give you a graphical interface to simply drag and drop your project folder onto your desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using Putty, I'll assume you are working on Windows. There is a GUI tool called [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/index.php) that works similar to Putty (i.e. over SSH and uses private keys and stuff) and can be used to access the remote server's filesystem. It has a pretty simple to understand UI which will be divided into you local filesystem and the server filesystem. Once you're connected and have reached the files you need you can just drag and drop the files into your local filesystem side.

If you would like to explore some command line options, its basically any tool that does `scp`. I think Putty comes with `scp` or `pscp` installed already. You can check by just typing in the command in your cmd/powershell.

Answer (score 0):

You can download [pscp.exe](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest.html) from PuTTY website and then:

Open cmd.exe and type:

```
pscp your_username_here@yourcompany.com:/path/to/file C:\Path\To\The\New File
```